# Collecting a specific cell value in multiple worksheets and display those values in a master sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to collect value from cell C3 of all worksheets. And display those values in vertical order of a master worksheet.

**Example:** There are values Tom, Peter, Mark in cell C3 of 3 worksheet. I would like to collect those values and display in C3 -> Tom, C4 -> Peter, C5 -> Mark in the 4th worksheet.

What function in excel should I use? Please help.

Comment: |=Sheet1!C3 for Tom in Sheet4 ,C3 |
|=Sheet2!C3 for Peter in Sheet4 ,C4 |
|=Sheet3!C3 for Mark in Sheet4 ,C5 | Assuming Sheet1 C3 contains Tom, Sheet2 C3 contains Peter and Sheet3 C3 contains Mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will loop through and grab Range("C3") from each sheet except the target sheet.

Make sure you change **Target_sheet_name** to your actual target sheet name.

```
Sub Grab_Names_From_Each_Sheet()
    Target_sheet_name = "Sheet1"
    Column_Num = 2
    For Each Sh In ActiveWorkbook
        If Sh.Name <> Target_sheet_name Then
            Column_Num = Column_Num + 1
            SHEETS(Target_sheet_name).Cells(3, Column_Num) = Sh.Range("C3")
        End If
    Next Sh
End Sub
```